# Can you run a user-defined pass before ASAN sanitizer?

Tags: address-sanitizer, sanitizer

I compile my code with -fsanitize=address switch. I have my own llvm pass that I want to execute. By the time the pass starts, I can see that the ASAN pass was made. Is it possible to run my pass before the ASAN pass?

Answer (score 0):

I‘ve also tried to run my pass before the ASAN pass in different ways to instrument my program at BasicBlock-level.

And this seems to be available for me:

Register a "StandardPasses" with `EP_EarlyAsPossible` flag which makes your pass works earlier than ASAN.

```
static RegisterStandardPasses Y(PassManagerBuilder::EP_EarlyAsPossible,
                                [](const PassManagerBuilder &Builder,
                                   legacy::PassManagerBase &PM) {
                                  PM.add(new MyPass());
                                });
```

Compile your pass as a ".so" file.

Then use `clang -Xclang -load -Xclang xxYourPassxx.so -fsanitize=address main.c -o main` to compile your code.

---

I also compiled the main.bc & main.ll for checking. And the results show me that my instrumentation doesn't appear in ASAN's block (Because my pass runs before ASAN).